# CGDisplayForceToGray function replication

Tags: swift, grayscale

I am trying to programmatically switch the whole screen to grayscale mode, but the `CGDisplayForceToGray` function has disappeared in Swift 4(?). Is there another function or method to replicate the `CGDisplayForceToGray` effect or has Apple deprecated functions of this kind entirely? Thank you.

Edit: For example, the code for [Desaturate](https://github.com/seenaburns/Desaturate) has a function called `CGDisplayForceToGray()` which turns the whole screen into `grayscale` mode, in the same way, that the "Use Grayscale" checkbox in the Accessibility Preferences turns the screen into grayscale. See below (this code is from Desaturate):

```
import Cocoa
import Carbon

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
  @IBOutlet weak var statusMenu: NSMenu!

  var grayscaleStatus = false;
  var preferencesWindow: PreferencesWindow!

  // For MASShortcut
  let callback = {}
  let defaultsKey = "global_shortcut"

  @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!

  @IBAction func quitAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    NSApplication.sharedApplication().terminate(self)
  }

  @IBAction func toggleAction(sender: AnyObject) {
   self.toggleGrayscale()
  }

 func toggleGrayscale() {
   grayscaleStatus = !grayscaleStatus
   CGDisplayForceToGray(grayscaleStatus)
   }
```

However, when I tried to use the `CGDisplayForceToGray()` function myself, I get the **Use of unresolved identifier** error. My guess is that the `CGDisplayForceToGray()` function was deleted or isn't functional anymore, but I was wondering if there were other alternatives to this function that don't use AppleScript.

Edit: **Resolved.**

Comment: A very quick search verifies what I think - was there **ever** any `CGDisplayForceToGray`? Why do you believe that a language version introduced some 9 months ago suddenly deprecated such a thing?

Comment: Sorry, this fits as a second comment. What are your needs? What code are you trying? (And without cluttering things up for a third comment, there are several ways for make an image greyscale. But maybe that isn't what you actually are looking for?) I **get** your issue - but I'm not getting the specifics. Maybe with some I can help? By specifics, maybe code will help and maybe explaining *how* you used to *"...switch the whole screen to greyscale mode..."* would. Thanks.

Comment: I've added some edits above to address some of your suggestions and questions.

Comment: `import Carbon`? Ouch. That predates me - don't get me wrong, I understand what that line of code means... But are you saying with *any* version of Swift I can copy/paste and get your code to run?

Comment: `CGDisplayForceToGray()` is a *non-public* function in the Core Graphics framework. That "Desaturate" project "tricks" by declaring the function in "Bridge.h". That is fragile, can fail or crash in future macOS versions, and might be a reason for App Store rejection.

Comment: @MartinR how does this "trick" work?

Comment: What does *"Edit: Resolved."* mean? If you solved your problem then post an answer.